# c++ -- Visual Studio 2010 Linker Error LNK1104: 'cannot open file Debug\AssemblyInfo.obj' [.obj files are not created at compile time]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker-errors

After a great deal of searching and head banging, i'm asking this question.

I started a new Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2010. Gave it a name and stored it in a location. Nothing added or edited in the same. No changes in the project properties either.

[Here](http://i299.photobucket.com/albums/mm298/aabond/Capture_zpsdc5768a4.jpg) is a copy of the Solutions Explorer.

I'm building the empty form and I get the following error.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 27/11/2013 1:35:27 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\TestProject.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CoreResGen:
1>  Processing resource file "Form1.resX" into "Debug\TestProject.Form1.resources".
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\AssemblyInfo.obj'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.41
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Now I have checked every damn page relevant to the error (6 hrs. of googling!!)
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx) is a list of the possible errors as suggested by MSDN. Now I'm new to MSVS 10, so I figure out that the `.obj` file is not present in the Debug Window, but `AssemblyInfo.cpp` is present. What should I do in the project settings so that the `.obj` gets compiled and the error goes away.

**Update**: Still no answers!! I'm amazed how NOBODY is getting this issue. Here is what I have tried soo far and the following happens:

1. Opened new Visual C++ Windows Forms Application (no modifications!)
2. Write ABSOLUTELY NO CODE.
3. Build Project

And the error occurs.

**Next**

1. Opened an old solution, where the .obj files were present.
2. Made a rebuild of the solution.

Same Error.
I look up the solution in the windows explorer. All .obj files are gone(which should happen as a rebuild would clean the .obj files). But what remains are onlt the `.log` files.

Thus, I have isolated the error that the compilation is not occuring as the linker files are not being created. As a result, the linker error `LNK1104` or `LNK1181` happen.

Can somebody tell me *why* is this problem. Has anyone seen this before. Can anyone provide a solution, if possible??

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild? Restart VS?

Comment: Yup. Tried and still the same :(

Comment: I got the same problem, but only after I deleted a .cpp (inputhandler.cpp). Now, it is telling me "cannot open Debug/inputhandler.obj"! I did try to rebuild, clean and restart. Help?

Comment: Reinstall VS. That might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem got solved long ago.

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\AssemblyInfo.obj'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

This was happening because the file `Debug\AssemblyInfo.obj`was simply *not being created*. This was due an error in the VS registries.

I did a clean, **fresh install of windows and VS**. This fixed the registry issues, and the file was being created perfectly.

I hope this helps people. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler says there are not modification in any of the files "Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files." So it'll skip the compilation phase (which generates the .obj files).

But the linker needs these files and for some reason they don't exist (at least that's what you claim is happening).

So you can try to force the compilation by doing a clean and than rebuild.

EDIT:

This particular issue can also be caused by specifying a dependency to a lib file that has spaces in its path. The path needs to be surrounded by quotes for the project to compile correctly.

On the Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input tab of the project’s properties, there is an Additional Dependencies property.

`C:\Program Files\<lib>`   -> `"C:\Program Files\<lib>"`

Comment: even I was thinking the same. But opening the solution in windows explorer showed that the `.obj` files were not created after build. That is the reason that the error keeps showing up.

Comment: do you have write permissions to the folder you are building in? I've seen similar problems when the folder you are building in is read-only (for whatever reason Windows decides)

Comment: This is a folder present in the Desktop. I don't think that may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently and it turned out to be due to the fact that I'd forgotten to unset `/P` in my compiler settings. Even though it seems like your problem is distinct, we both got the same error message.

When you preprocess to a file, `cl` stops producing `.obj` files.

Comment: This is true, although unrelated to the error from the questioner. I ran into this specific problem